# How to move a bitmap object around a screen, and have multiple objects using the same bitmap

Tags: c#, winforms, graphics, gdi+

See above.

I need to move my bitmaps around a Form, or perhaps inside a PictureBox in a form. I have not been able to find any tutorials on this specific subject, and even the base GDI+ stuff is a bit confusing. I am looking for a simple and THOROUGHLY explained way on how to do this.

I am needing this for a rendering engine for an 8-bit game I am collaborating on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GDI+ may not be the best option.

Sprites are generally drawn using "blitting". However, I've read (perhaps outdated?) claims that GDI+ blit operations are slow because they're not hardware accelerated.

If this is 8-bit game rendering, maybe you don't care - but maybe you could use [SDL.NET](http://cs-sdl.sourceforge.net/index.php/Main_Page).

In particular, try [this](http://cs-sdl.sourceforge.net/index.php/Surfaces) tutorial. You should probably follow that first bit of advice (do the hello world first) but this is worth a skim through first to see if it fits.

**EDIT** - actually, there's not much tutorial there ATM. The main SDL docs (for the C version) are probably OK, but it's still a bit of a pain. Oh well.

Comment: What I mean is the SDL C docs are probably adequate for working with the SDL.NET library in C#. Not ideal, but - depending on how many other things your juggling at the same time - possibly usable. Since the tutorial is a wiki, I may expand it a bit myself, but I'll have to get back into practice with C# first or I'll just screw things up anyway.